# Scraping Facebook always gives me Login info data Android

Tags: android, facebook, screen-scraping, userinfo

Ok i know Facebook does not let us retrieve information like emails and phone numbers of our friends, but I am trying to get it through scrapping. Only problem is that I always end up getting html data for the login page and not the user info page itself. Even though my webview is showing the info page still I am not able to get the html data of that page. Any sorta help will be highly appreciated. My code is

```
StringBuffer myString = new StringBuffer();
             try {
                 String thisLine;
                 URL u = new URL(myWebView.getUrl());//url is http://m.facebook.com/username?v=info
                 DataInputStream theHTML = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
                 while ((thisLine = theHTML.readLine()) != null) {
                     myString.append(thisLine);
                 } 
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get much help breaking Facebook's TOS to scrape the site like this

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. Just as you need to log in each time you use a different browser, you would need to log in with the Java HTTP fetcher.

Comment: but i am also saving session cookie separately for the webview in which im trying to open. wouldnt that help?

Comment: your `u.openStream()` doesn't send that cookie to facebook. You'll have to use a more advanced library to send HTTP requests including cookies.